# Is there a way to add a web link to a word with ctrl-l in the comments section?

Tags: support

Maybe I was just doing something wrong, but I was having trouble using ctrl-l to link a website to a word in a comment.  Is this possible, and if not could it be made possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:
"[word](https://www.google.com/)"

[word](https://www.google.com/)